# XMLstarlet delete multiple duplcated tags based on sequence

Tags: xmlstarlet

I would be thankful for any help on the below XML:

```xml
<products>
    <product>
        <Title>Name of product 1</Title>
        <SKU>00016</SKU>
        <Price>1.98</Price>
        <Stock>95</Stock>
        <Price>1.98</Price>
    </product>
        <product>
        <Title>Name of product 2</Title>
        <SKU>00017</SKU>
        <Price>2.15</Price>
        <Stock>45</Stock>
        <Price>2.15</Price>
    </product>
</products>
```

the field of XML is duplicated in every product and I need to delete the one of those two in every product.

I tried this:
`xmlstarlet sel -t -c'//Price[1]' -n filename.xml > temp.txt && xmlstarlet ed -d '//Price[1]' filename.xml > tmp.xml && mv tmp.xml filename_corrected.xml`

but it **only** is removed in the first product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the YAML processor [mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) instead of xmlstarlet to solve your task:

```bash
yq --input-format xml --output-format xml '.products.product |= map(.Price |= .[0])' "$FILE"
```

**Output**

```xml
<products>
  <product>
    <Title>Name of product 1</Title>
    <SKU>00016</SKU>
    <Price>1.98</Price>
    <Stock>95</Stock>
  </product>
  <product>
    <Title>Name of product 2</Title>
    <SKU>00017</SKU>
    <Price>2.15</Price>
    <Stock>45</Stock>
  </product>
</products>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it already, found a very similar answer on an other question, but did not manage to install yq to my system. On local system it works great and correct. But thank you again.

Comment: I installed yq to the server finally and works perfectly. Thanks for once more. Any answers using xmlstarlet are also welcome for syntax help

Answer (score 0):

With xmlstartlet, it's simply

```
xml ed -d  '//Price[1]'   yourfile.xml
```

Output should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @weby Good to hear! If we're done, please don't forget to accept the answer.